# Extracting a value from an array

Tags: arrays, cocoa-touch, ios7

So I have this

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[status valueForKey:@"coordinates"]);
```

Which gives me this

```
{
    coordinates =     (
        "-91.17785719",
        "30.41023765"
    );
    type = Point;
}
```

How can I just extract the longitude and latitude from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so status[@"coordinates"] is another dictionary with another coordinates key?

if so then try this:
`status[@"coordinates"][@"coordinates"][0]`

that will yield the string "-91.17785719"
using 1 instead of 0 will get the other value